# How can I use my own annotation for Swagger?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

How can I use my own annotation for building swagger ui page.
For example I defined annotation and use it:

```
    @PUT
    @MyOwnAnnotationForAdditionalPropInSwagger(value = "Some text")
    @Path( "/{carId}" )
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(
        value = "Updates car info"
    )
    public Response patchItem(@ApiParam(value = "Fields to update") Car item) {
            /*some code*/
    }
```

After that probably I should extend some class from `swagger-core` and specify to scan my annotation (`@MyOwnAnnotationForAdditionalPropInSwagger`).

As result I want to see additional column in swagger ui with my text.

How I can realize it? What class I need to extend?

Comment: You're a bit off track here because you're missing the idea behind Swagger. It's a specification, and extending it is not that simple. We do have a way to add vendor extensions which would have translated support in the ecosystem tools, but randomly extending it is just not something we support.

Answer (score 1):

The swagger 2.0 supports custom fields, there was a Pull Request for this back in 2013 (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node/pull/47).

While apparently it's easy to add the custom fields, since they are not present in the Swagger 2.0 spec, Swagger-UI won't display them by default.

For this to work you will have to change a couple of things.

1. Implement the desired annotation in your parser implementation (*ie.* `swagger-core` or `swagger-php`) if it doesn't exist.
2. Clone and modify `swagger-ui` to display your custom field as you wish.

Note that by doing this you will in fact violate the swagger json schema (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/schemas/v2.0/schema.json) and any third party validators you may use will fail.

Comment: How can I implement my annotation in `swagger-core` parser?

Comment: Well assuming you are using `java` you will have to extend the `swagger-core` library, which you can find here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core. The specifics you can find by reading the documentation: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki.

Comment: We are talking here about a full development cycle. This falls outside the scope of the question as the answer would be the implementation itself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do ca be achieved extending the swagger core reader as described in [swagger documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Extensions#extending-reader). Here is an example in one of my [projects](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j-jaxrs/blob/99a559da7204d3a930637ac6fe623c9e2bb9d059/spf4j-jaxrs-open-api/src/main/java/org/spf4j/actuator/open_api/CustomReader.java).